# Create column of array of differences between two adjacent numbers in another column's array python/pyspark

Tags: python, arrays, loops, pyspark, difference

I have a column of arrays made of numbers, ie [0,80,160,220], and would like to create a column of arrays of the differences between adjacent terms, ie [80,80,60]

Does anyone have an idea how to do this in Python/PySpark? my code is `df=df.withcolumn('col_array_diffs', [df.col_array.getItem[i]-df.col_array.getItem[i-1] if i else None for i in range(1,F.size(df.col_array))])` but am really struggling with the arraytype. This produces AssertionError: col should be Column...Thanks!

Comment: You can try using `.cast("Integer")` such as `df=df.withcolumn('col_array_diffs', [df.col_array.getItem[i].cast("Integer")-df.col_array.getItem[i-1].cast("Integer") if i else None for i in range(1,F.size(df.col_array))])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a UDF to do this.

```py
import pyspark.sql.types as T

def subtract_el(x):
    return [abs(i-j) for i, j in list(zip(x, x[1:]))]

df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame([[[0,80,160,220]]]))
df.select(F.udf(subtract_el, T.ArrayType(T.IntegerType()))("0").alias("diff")).show()
```

Results in :

```
+------------+
|        diff|
+------------+
|[80, 80, 60]|
+------------+
```